# The following packages are in a mess due to serious problems during installation

Tags: software-installation, package-management, dpkg, debian-installer

I am unable to reinstall a package (`libturbojpeg0`). I have the following error

```
# dpkg --audit                       
The following packages are in a mess due to serious problems during
installation.  They must be reinstalled for them (and any packages
that depend on them) to function properly:
 libturbojpeg0:amd64  TurboJPEG runtime library - SIMD optimized
```

I cannot remove it

```
# apt-get remove  libturbojpeg0
[...]
dpkg: error processing package libturbojpeg0:amd64 (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libturbojpeg0:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**What can I do in order to reinstall this package?**

Comment: `libturbojpeg0` is not part of the current stable Debian Jessie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should ask `apt-get` to reinstall it:

```
 apt-get --reinstall install libturbojpeg0:amd64
```